# Azure Functions: How does the life-cycle work?

Tags: architecture, lifecycle, azure-functions

I'm running into some problems with Azure Functions where a Function App which deployed properly and worked great, now claims to be missing dependencies (NodeJS) and errors out the next day when testing. If I understood the life-cycle of how Azure Functions work, I think I could troubleshoot and fix this easier.

Can anyone explain the life-cycle or point me to the documentation I can't seem to find?

For example, I'm using continuous deployment. With this method it appears that there is a default deploy.cmd that is used to:

1. Git clone/pull the repository to D:\Site\repository
2. Run npm install on the repository.
3. Kudosync (whatever this means) these files to D:\Site\wwwroot

This all works beautifully. What I'm wondering is what happens next.

e.g. The function sits unused for a period of time and therefore I assume its spun down and taken "out-of-order"?

When its access again, it needs to spin something up again.

- Does it go through the deployment process again (Doesn't seem like it).
- What/where/how does it restore files back to the instance?
- Is this the same process which is used when scaling the app?

Comment: Could you provide some details like what error messages you're seeing? Deployment happens once, then the individual instances use a network share to access the content. So if it works once, then it should work again until the next deployment.

Comment: That definitely has not been my experience. I'm being told that npm modules are missing that were installed and functioning a day earlier.

Comment: Are there any error conditions that would result in something different?

Comment: There is a possibility you may be running into this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/298 but I'm speculating. If you can share details about the error you're seeing, that would help.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT If you want to write an overview of the network share/etc, I will definitely accept it as this answer (Since that was my question).

Comment: @FabioCavalcante Thank-you for that link. I think that is directly related to the behavior/problem I've seen.

Comment: There are some customer workarounds on that same issue thread on how to use webpack to improve the startup time: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/298#issuecomment-273317953

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you deploy something to Azure Functions, there's a few options, but most go through you .scm site (aka. Kudu). Kudu interacts with the file system for you, which is generally a network share of some kind (for Consumption plan, it's Azure Files; for App Service plans, it's built into App Service).

So let's say I `git push` content to my Function App via Kudu, after the content is updated, Kudu will take the content in the repository and "deploy" it to the `./site/wwwroot` folder after running any deployment scripts you've got.

The Function App's host then sees file changes, and picks up the changes to your Functions. If your Function on a given instance writes anything to disk, it will be seen by the other instances as well.

Here's a much simplified diagram of how that looks:
[image]

As Fabio mentioned, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/298) we have right now for Functions which have large quantities of files that need to be loaded (even if it's just 1 require statement, there may be hundreds of files that it depends on) that causes them to take abnormally long times to load the first time due to Azure Files being slow to handle large amount of requests, especially under load from scaling. We've got a plan to address this in the near future. In the mean time, you can use App Service plans or reduce the number of dependent files (even if the content size is roughly the same).

Comment: thanks!! if my azure function app has 2 functions `func1` & `func2` so they will be running as child in-process under `Function Host` main process? can any crash in `func1` bring down whole Function Host and thereby impact `func2` as well?

Comment: I no longer work for Microsoft/Azure Functions and can't speak with authority on this. In theory, it is possible. Since this post, the functional backend has separated more and more of the execution from the host. In practice, that means it's difficult, but anything sharing user space can risk impacting one another.